# Cloning from BitBucket to GIT without login?

Tags: git, bitbucket

There is a project on BitBucket that I just want to download to experiment with.  I am new to GIT.  The clone button displays a hg command and the URL has no .git, so I assume this is not the URL I need for GIT.  I tried anyways(also tried adding a .git to the end) and got a "not found" error in both cases.

```
$ git clone https://bitbucket.org/munificent/amaranth.git


fatal:https://bitbucket.org/munificent/amaranth not found did you git
 update server-info on the server ?
```

I am not sure what the error is suggesting.  It sounds like it is recommending I run a command  on the server side which I can't since I am not the owner of the repo.

Is downloading this repo from bit bucket possible without mercurial?  If so, how?  Even just an archive file would be nice.

I am using GitHub for windows command line.  (I didn't see an obvious way to just enter a URL into the GitHub user interface, which I feel like I've just not found it, since it seems that a URL is what I keep seeing offered as the primary way to clone a repo, along with SSH)

Comment: It displays an hg command because its a mercurial repository. You need to use a mercurial client to clone it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that.  Thought that might be the case but wasn't sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a small download link on the bottom of this thing:

[image]

It seems to point to a [zipball of the latest commit](https://bitbucket.org/munificent/amaranth/get/b6be068243e4.zip).

Comment: You get that when clicking the Clone button at the top?  I only get the HTTPS part with the URL.  Odd, thanks for the link.

Comment: @AaronLS: I just went to https://bitbucket.org/munificent/amaranth and it was on the right side.

Comment: @AaronLS: BTW, cloning a Mercurial repo is almost exactly the same as cloning a Git repo. `hg clone ...`.